# How to run cypress tests with tags in nrwl nx workspace

Tags: typescript, cypress, pipeline, nrwl-nx

I am working in a nrwl nx workspace,, I have a cypress BDD cucumber project set up in it.
I need to run cypress tests based on tags using nrwl.

Normally i would use cypress-tags command to do the same:
eg: `"cypress run --env TAGS='@smoke' --browser chrome` "

I applied the same logic to an nx command.
eg: `nx e2e myProject-e2e --tags=@reg`

But the nx project is identifying all test cases in cypress, it does not take into consideration the test cases tagged with tag "@reg"

Can someone guide me if there is a provision in nrwl to run cypress tests based on tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and got a workaround by using the ENV object from the [NX configuration](https://nx.dev/packages/cypress/executors/cypress):

This way, I added the tags in the `project.json` configuration file, in my case for running the smoke test and a regression test based on the tags filtering:

```
"smoke": {
  "executor": "@nrwl/cypress:cypress",
  "options": {
    "cypressConfig": "apps/explore-e2e/cypress.json",
    "baseUrl": "<BASE_URL>",
    "env": {
      "TAGS": "@smoke"
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "staging": {
      "baseUrl": "<STG_URL>"
    },
    "production": {
      "baseUrl": "<PROD_URL>"
    }
  }
},
"regression": {
  "executor": "@nrwl/cypress:cypress",
  "options": {
    "cypressConfig": "apps/explore-e2e/cypress.json",
    "baseUrl": "<BASE_URL>",
    "env": {
      "TAGS": "@regression"
    }
  },
  "configurations": {
    "staging": {
      "baseUrl": "<STG_URL>"
    },
    "production": {
      "baseUrl": "<PROD_URL>"
    }
  }
}
```

With this, you can now start tagging your scenarios and running it with:

```
nx e2e myProject-e2e:smoke --TAGS=@smoke
```

(In my case I'm using: `yarn nx run` instead)

Comment: Thank you jose_manuel_cordero this worked for me. How Do i run multiple suites with this method ? Eg: If i want to run smoke as well as regression tagged tests. I tried --TAGS='@smoke or @reg' but it did not work for me. It ran all test cases.

Comment: Have had no luck with this answer and using `EXCLUDE_TAGS` unfortunatelzy

Answer (score 0):

you can use "configurations" features in NX to have multiple tags

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying your tags in the env section of the cypress.config.ts file? I specify tags here and this filters out tests that I run through the Cypress runner:

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
 env: { 
    tsConfig: 'tsConfig.json',
    tags: '@a',
 },
 <other configs here>
```

Similarly to filter out when running command line:

```
nx e2e myproject-e2e --env.tags=@a
```